# '2023-02-07 10:49:00' instead of '2023-02-07 05:49:00'

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, pytz

I am very confused right now. Here is the timestamp 1675766940000. What is the time using this time format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. On my local machine, the answer is '2023-02-07 05:49:00' and on a docker container located in my local machine the answer is '2023-02-07 10:49:00'. It makes much more sense that the answer is '2023-02-07 05:49:00'. Here is the code I use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(1675766940000)/1000).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` Is there anything I can do to fix that issue?

I tried

```
import datetime
import pytz

timestamp = 1675766940000 / 1000
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, pytz.UTC)
formatted_time = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
print(formatted_time)
```

and

```
import datetime

timestamp = 1675766940000 / 1000  # Convert milliseconds to seconds
dt_utc = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
formatted_time = dt_utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(formatted_time)
```

but I am still getting '2023-02-07 10:49:00'. Be aware that I am using python 3.8.10.

Comment: The best option is to *not* use a Unix timestamp but actual dates. . All databases (except SQLite) have native support for dates, Excel supports dates natively  and the standard way to specify dates as text is the ISO8601 format. If you care about timezones and offsets, include the offset in the string or use a `datetimeoffset` or the equivalent type

Comment: It is because I am pulling data from a data vendor. So he provides me this timestamp 1675766940000. I have to deal with it

Comment: You are getting the correct answer. The `datetime` object knows what timezone was used to create it, and preserves that in the formatted string. If you want to convert that timestamp to another timezone (or as in your edit, creating a local timestamp in the first place), you need to do so explicitly.

Comment: Even when you use `utcfromtimestamp` you get a naive datetime object, ie one that doesn't know what its timezone is, so it's treated as local. If the offset is really UTC you need to use `datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, timezone.utc)`. Otherwise, use the timezone that corresponds to the data

Comment: I suspect that container is configured for UTC, which is why you get a different result. If you want to display dates in EST, change the container's timezone, don't try to parse the UTC timestamp as if it was an EST timestamp

Comment: I think understanding the difference between [Aware and Naive Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) would be a good place to start. Then, if you have Unix time, it refers to 1970-01-01 **UTC**. It does **not** give you any time zone information other than that.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an acceptable answer:

```
import datetime
import pytz

est = pytz.timezone('EST')
timestamp = 1675766940000 / 1000
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=est)
formatted_time = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
print(formatted_time)
```

Comment: No, hard-coding the timezone is never acceptable. Who said this is Estonia Summer Time? And don't say this is East US - says who? The acronyms are ambiguous. You don't know if that timestamp was in UTC or your local timezone. And the local timezone may be UTC if you run your code in a cloud or hosted environment. By default all cloud VMs and services run on UTC

Comment: Why do you think your answer is acceptable? It's completely lacking an explanation. That's the opposite of acceptable!

Comment: What timezone are the data in? That's the one you need to specify in `tz`, not your local one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).